# How to call capistrano from ansible script

Tags: ruby, capistrano, ansible

My problem is a bit tricky. I was given a task to make an deployment script for a system build in Ruby(not developed by me). This project already has a capistrano deployment that works fine as long as the machine has a previous setup. My task is to automate this setup without touching the capistrano part. Since I have no knowledge of capistrano and have very litle time to do it I decided to use ansible.

The idea is to run the ansible script, this sets up the machine and call capistrano to deploy the project. I tried the following tasks and all produced some errors:

```
- name: Run cap
  shell: "cap generic_production deploy"
  environment:
    MACHINE: localhost
  args:
    chdir: /home/{{ansible_user_id}}/project
```

```sh
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cap generic_production deploy", "delta": "0:00:00.106225", "end": "2016-07-06 15:54:42.482794", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-07-06 15:54:42.376569", "stderr": "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
  from Capfile:2:in `load'\
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
  from /usr/bin/cap:4:in `<main>'", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

```
- name: Run cap
  shell: "bundle exec cap generic_production deploy"
  environment:
    MACHINE: localhost
  args:
    chdir: /home/{{ansible_user_id}}/project
```

```sh
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "bundle exec cap generic_production deploy", "delta": "0:00:00.001287", "end": "2016-07-06 15:50:21.472625", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-07-06 15:50:21.471338", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

```
- name: Run cap
  shell: "sudo -iu {{ansible_user_id}} bundle exec cap generic_production deploy"
  environment:
    MACHINE: localhost
  args:
    chdir: /home/{{ansible_user_id}}/project
```

```sh
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo -iu deploy bundle exec cap generic_production deploy", "delta": "0:00:00.230098", "end": "2016-07-06 15:28:42.623268", "failed": true, "rc": 10, "start": "2016-07-06 15:28:42.393170", "stderr": "", "stdout": "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory", "stdout_lines": ["Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"], "warnings": ["Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo"]}
```

Is there a way to call capistrano from ansible or it can't be done?

EDIT:
The generic_production is a deployment script that uses **MACHINE** as target.

Comment: Capistrano generally needs to run on your local machine and Ansible is all about running commands on the remote machine. Are you sure this is practical? I'm not sure what `MACHINE` is, it seems non-standard.

Comment: I don't think this is practical. Ideally I would redesign all with ansible. But I lack in time for that or to learn how to setup with capistrano.  Is there a way for capistrano to run locally?

Comment: I'm saying that Capistrano intrinsically runs local, executing remote commands over SSH. Ansible is similar. Running Capistrano through Ansible means running...remote commands from the remote server to the remote server? They're two tools trying to do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me if the ansible playbook is run from the directory you'd normall run `cap` from.

```
- name: capistrano deploy
  local_action: shell cap generic_production deploy
  become: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run your cap deploy on a remote machine then local_action isn't right.  Here's an tiny task that works for an rbenv environment (and possibly rvm but I didn't test that):

```
- name: Run Capistrano
  shell: bash -lc "bundle exec cap production deploy"
     chdir=/home/ubuntu/rails/myapp
```

The -lc trick is key here since that runs this as a login shell forcing your rbenv settings to be executed.